# Problem using JS to validate entry on client-side form (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, client-side

I'm having trouble running validation for the following form.

Each input is supposed to show:

a) a red border and a red exclamation circle(appears after input) for incorrect entry.

b) or set a green border and green check circle (appears after input) if it is a correct input.

Can anyone help/spot what I am doing wrong?

Thanks all

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b9f255870f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontawesome/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="JavaScript" href="js/script.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Business Contact Us</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="main_body">
        <!-- Merch Section & Folder Structure-->
        <div class="form-body">
            <div id="form-error"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <form id="contactus_form" class="contactus_form">
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                        <small>Error Message</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName">
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle "></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                        <small>Error Message</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="companyPosition">Position</label>
                        <input type="text" id="companyPosition" name="companyPosition">
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                        <small>Error Message</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                        <small>Error Message</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control ">
                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                        <small>Error Message</small>
                    </div>
                    <button class="contactus-form-submitbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-body {
    min-height: 1300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0px;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000010;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contactus-form {
    padding: 30px 40px;
}

.form-control {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
}

.form-control label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 18 px;
}

.form-control input {
    border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-control.success input {
    border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.form-control.error input {
    border-color: #e74c3c;
}

.form-control textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.199);
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.form-control i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 10px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
    color: #2ecc71;
    visibility: visible;
}

.form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
    color: #e74c3c;
    visibility: visible;
}

.form-control small {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.contactus-form-submitbtn {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(31, 136, 229);
    border: 1px solid rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.199);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

label#disclaimer-label {
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.form-group-disclaimer {
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

**JS**

```
const contactus_form = document.getElementById('contactus_form');
const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
const lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
const companyPosition = document.getElementsById('companyPosition');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const message = document.getElementById('message');

contactus_form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {

    const firstNameValue = firstName.value.trim();
    const lastNameValue = lastName.value.trim();
    const companyPositionValue = companyPosition.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const messageValue = message.value.trim();

    if (firstNameValue === '') {

        setErrorFor(firstNameValue, 'First name cannot be blank');
    } else {

        setSuccessFor(firstNameValue);
    }

    if (lastNameValue === '') {

        setErrorFor(lastNameValue, 'Last name cannot be blank');
    } else {

        setSuccessFor(lastNameValue);
    }

    if (companyPositionValue === '') {

        setErrorFor(companyPositionValue, 'Company position cannot be blank');
    } else {

        setSuccessFor(companyPositionValue);
    }

    if (emailValue === '') {

        setErrorFor(emailValue, 'Email cannot be blank');
    } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
        setErrorFor(emailValue, 'Not a valid email')
    } else {

        setSuccessFor(emailValue);
    }

    if (messageValue === '') {

        setErrorFor(messageValue, 'Message cannot be blank');
    } else {

        setSuccessFor(messageValue);
    }
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');

    small.innerText = message;

    formControl.className = 'form-control error';

}

function setSuccessFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}

function isEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}
```

Comment: I would argue that "what you're doing wrong" is using JS for form validation in 2021... `<input type="email" required />` along with CSS `:valid` or `:invalid` pseudo-classes are the way to go, and if you still want JS to augment it further then use `input.validity.valid` to test for validity, or more specific properties like `input.validity.typeMismatch` on your email input to test if it's an invalid email address.

Comment: Tried this, no luck I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spaces in each of your ID attributes, e.g:

```
id="companyPosition "
```

Try removing those and see if it works then.

Comment: Adjusted the above, removing the spaces,and even edited the HTML, but still doesn't work